# Ruby efficienct queries

Tags: ruby, performance

So far in my new workplace I've been dealing with querying databases and finding out the most efficient ways of getting the desired data.
I've found out about using pluck and getting the desired attributes instead of loading the whole result in the memory and other tricks, such as using inject (reduce), map, reject and such, which made my life a whole lot easier.
However, I haven't exactly found any theoretical explanation why inject/map/reject should be used in order to gain higher efficiency, only some sort of empiric conclusions from my own attempts. Like, why should I use map instead of iterating over an array with an "each".

Could someone please shed some light?

Comment: "[I haven't found any explanation] why inject/map/reject should be used in order to gain higher efficiency" - because it doesn't give any efficiency benefits. They have no effect whatsoever on the database queries.

Comment: They make code cleaner and easier to read, not faster. Quite often, they even make code slower, because you, for example, use two chained `map`s instead of one `each`.

Comment: Oh alright, I've been told they're preferably used to make it faster. So the improvements must have been based on using pluck. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. If you'd like an explanation of if/why implementation A is superior to implementation B, then can you please **SHOW US** what *is* implementation A and B? Using `inject`, `map`, `reject`, etc are not "tricks", they are core features of the language. They may or may not be the best tool for the job, or have much impact to performance.

Comment: The most common performance improvements for such scenarios come from the database querying however, not so much from the ruby object manipulation. For example: Loading less data (as you already mentioned), or preventing N+1 queries, or creating optimal indexes on the database tables, or denormalising some critical columns, or even restructuring your database architecture.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Or slower if you use `map`, `select`, and other Enumerable methods when you should  be letting the database do the work.

Comment: I found your question too general and can't define to myself what kind of the answer you want to get here. 
`why should I use map instead of iterating over an array with an "each"?`  is an example of well defined question.

Comment: @TomLord Yeah, the part with placing more of the querying on the database rather than manipulating it myself in ruby is clear.
A concise example would be:
array = []
User.where(..).pluck(:id, :name, :number_of_purchases).each do |asd|
array << asd.number_of_purchases*2, etc

Or 
array = User.where(..).pluck(:id, :name, :number_of_purchases).inject([]) do |array,(id,name,number_of_purchases)|
array << number_of_purchases*2

Is there any difference performance wise, or is it just an aesthetic thing?
Also, the example was purely fictional, something I've made up on the spot.

Comment: Also I'd very much like to rewrite the above comment in a readable manner, but I've already reached the 5 edits/comment limit, so it's just gonna be ugly.

Comment: @AronLatis: yeah, you can't display multiline code blocks in comments anyway.

Comment: @AronLatis: there should be no noticeable performance difference, but you could check that yourself by using something like `benchmark-ips`. Aesthetics-wise, I'd reduce that to `array = User.where(...).pluck(...).map {|id, name, number_of_purchases| number_of_purchases * 2 }`

Comment: Note on benchmarking those two approaches: if you plug them into benchmark-ips as-is, you'd be measuring the database latency mostly. The runtime of the loops is negligible. Making good benchmarks is tricky.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Alright, I'll play around with benchmarks and come back if I get any relevant results. Thank you!